# Filter Google Flights Results

Tags: javascript, filtering

Is there some javascript I can use to filter the results displayed on [This Map](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=SFO;d=2014-12-04;r=2014-12-08;mc=m) by price ?

Looks like there are lot of different calls but I can't figure the object/array I should filter on.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: haha.. you've shamed me into taking a second look now. 
But I was/am having a hard time figuring out where to intercept that the data that's coming in from call to rpc (https://www.google.com/flights/rpc)

Comment: While it could be possible, I'd regard this kind of solution to be pretty brittle.  Perhaps try looking at generating RPC calls directly? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10210903/1059070

Comment: That's pretty neat. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the page before the Flight Maps page on google flight allows you to set a max price.

That's then reflected in the flight maps page URL in the `mp`  param (assume it means max price)

https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=SFO;d=2014-12-04;r=2014-12-08;mp=450;mc=m

Saves the trouble of having to write any code.